Share DbContext in Integration Testing
For making my integration tests I am using TestContainer package (SQL Server). I also have a BaseWebApplicationTest class to share some properties like HttpClient and AppDbContext.
This is my WebApplicationFactory:
public class IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory<TProgram>
    : WebApplicationFactory<TProgram>, IAsyncLifetime
    where TProgram : class
{
    private readonly MsSqlContainer _msSqlContainer = new MsSqlBuilder()
        .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
        .Build();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.RemoveAll<DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>>();
            services.AddSqlServer<AppDbContext>(_msSqlContainer.GetConnectionString());
        });
    }

    public Task InitializeAsync() => _msSqlContainer.StartAsync();

    public new Task DisposeAsync() => _msSqlContainer.StopAsync();
}

Here is my abstract class to share the properties I need in my test cases:
public abstract class BaseWebApplicationTest
{
    private readonly IServiceScope _scope;
    protected readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    protected readonly AppDbContext _context;

    protected BaseWebApplicationTest(IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _scope = factory.Services.CreateScope();
        _context = _scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<AppDbContext>();
        _httpClient = factory.CreateClient();
    }
}

Here is a sample of my user test controller:
[Collection(nameof(WebApplicationCollectionFixture))]
public class UserControllerTests(IntegrationTestWebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    : BaseWebApplicationTest(factory)
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task CreateUser_Should_Return201StatusCode_WhenUserDoesNotExist()
    {
        // Arrange
        var role = new Role()
        {
            Name = "admin",
            Description = "This is admin user",
        };
        await _context.Roles.AddAsync(role);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        CreateUserRequest request = new(
            "First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "user_name",
            "example@email.com",
            "Password123",
            RoleId: role.Id);

        // Act
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("/api/user", request);

        // Assertions
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        response.StatusCode
            .Should()
            .Be(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created);

        Guid userId = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Guid>();
        userId.Should().NotBeEmpty();

        var userCreated = await _context.Users.FindAsync(userId);
        
        userCreated.Should().NotBeNull();
        userCreated!.Id.Should().Be(userId);
        userCreated!.Username.Should().Be(request.UserName);
        // check others properties if you want...
    }
}

So far everything is okay. The problem comes when I try to update a user. The changes are not reflected in the context of the tests. I mean, after updating the user, I get it, but the changes is not reflected. Why?
Here is the test case:
[Fact]
public async Task Update_Should_Return200StatusCode_WhenRequestDataIsValid()
{
    // Arrange
    var role = new Role()
    {
        Name = "admin1x",
        Description = "This is admin user"
    };

    var user = new User()
    {
        FirstName = "First Name",
        LastName = "Last Name",
        Email = "email@example2.com",
        Password = "Pass123@",
        Username = "user_name3",
        Role = role
    };

    await _context.Roles.AddAsync(role);
    await _context.Users.AddAsync(user);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    CreateUserRequest request = new(
        "Name changed",
        "Last Name changed",
        "user_changed",
        "example_changed@email.com",
        "PassChanged123$",
        RoleId: role.Id);

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PutAsJsonAsync(
        $"/api/user/{user.Id}",
        request);
    
    // Assert
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);

    Guid id = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Guid>();
    id.Should().NotBeEmpty();
    
    var userChanged = await _context.Users.FindAsync(id); // I get the update user

    userChanged?.FirstName.Should().Be(request.FirstName);
    userChanged?.LastName.Should().Be(request.LastName);
    userChanged?.Username.Should().Be(request.UserName);
}

This is the error message of my the test:

Expected userChanged?.FirstName to be "Name changed" with a length of 12, but "First Name" has a length of 10, differs near "Fir" (index 0).

User update service is okay, because when I use _context.Entry(userChanged).Reload(); the test case is green.
Thoughts or advice is gratefully received...

...does your DI system treat each test as a scoped container (i.e. each test gets its own DbContext) - or is a Singleton? or Transient?

Did you try to making context static in base test class?

It's fundamentally wrong to use the same context in Arrange/Act/Assert stages. In real-life you won't Get the user by the same context that Put it.

This is because you are using FindAsync on the same DbContext instance that was used to create the user. After creating the user, it was stored in the DbContext cache. The FindAsync checks this cache first and returns the stale user object.
As a best practice, always use different DbContext instances to Arrange, Act, and Assert phases of the test. This will help you to avoid cache issues and also catch bugs when you forget to call SaveChangesAsync after adding or updating an entry in the DbContext.
